# How to Return a Shopping Cart Total

Tags: python, list, python-2.x

I've been at this for hours and I just can't seem to figure out how to return a total. All I know is that I need to start with total = 0. I have tried 'for i in x' loops and I wish I had them to post here but I've been doing trial and error for so long that I can't exactly recall what I've done. I'm using Python 2.7.10 and I'm a complete beginner. Please help? Even if just a hint?

```
f_list = []
print 'Enter a fruit name (or done):',
f = raw_input()
while f != 'done':
    print 'Enter a fruit name (or done):',
    f_list.append(f)
    f = raw_input()
print ""
p_list = []
for i in f_list:
    print 'Enter the price for ' + i + ':',
    p = float(raw_input())
    p_list.append(p)
print ""
print 'Your fruit list is: ' + str(f_list)
print 'Your price list is: ' + str(p_list)
print ""
n = len(f_list)
r = range(0,n)
q_list = []
for i in r:
    print str(f_list[i]) + '(' + '$' + str(p_list[i]) + ')',
    print 'Quantity:',
    q = raw_input()
total = 0
```

Comment: Which part you don't understand? You need to collect quantities of fruits and sum `quantity * price` for each fruit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have forgotten to create the list of quantities, which isn't going to help.
Then just iterate over your `f_list` and add them up.

```
f_list = []
print 'Enter a fruit name (or done):',
f = raw_input()
while f != 'done':
    print 'Enter a fruit name (or done):',
    f_list.append(f)
    f = raw_input()
print ""
p_list = []
for i in f_list:
    print 'Enter the price for ' + i + ':',
    p = float(raw_input())
    p_list.append(p)
print ""
print 'Your fruit list is: ' + str(f_list)
print 'Your price list is: ' + str(p_list)
print ""
q_list = []
for i in range(len(f_list)):
    print str(f_list[i]) + '(' + '$' + str(p_list[i]) + ')',
    print 'Quantity:',
    q = raw_input()
    q_list.append(q)
total = 0
for i in range(len(f_list)):
    total += float(p_list[i]) * int(q_list[i])
print "Basket value : ${:.2f}".format(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are definitely other answers on this site that should help you, but you want to convert your q to a float and append q to q_list just like for p.  To get your grand total all you need to do is `total = sum(q_list)` and display your answer.